# How can websites fingerprint the company I work for?

Tags: identity, fingerprinting, identification

During my work day, I came upon a website that had a popup that identified the company I work for(basically saying "contact us X company"). This website was never previously visited, cookies were blocked and the company I work for is relatively small. Typically when thinking about finger printing, the data is usually just browser information and IP address that gives a vague idea of location and what the person is running. I've never seen it straight up get the name of the company. How could they have done this?

Comment: Too much unknowns. Is the public IP of the company static and maybe even via whois or similar clearly associated with the company?

Comment: Can you Share the Website?

Comment: Browser fingerprinting requires a lot of data and JavaScript APIs and such elements as canvas, WebGL and similar technologies allow additional data to be gathered. To fully know, you would need to analyze the source code. What @SteffenUllrich is referring to is also known as a PTR Record in DNS, that might actually be the case to verify that it's actually the company X and not Y.

Comment: Is this possible if the browser is in a stealth mode | inkognito mode, or is this only possible over the ip/dns scan?

Answer (score 1):

These analytics tools (such as "Lead Forensics") typically have a database of IP addresses and the companies that they're associated with. It's not perfect by any means, but since a lot of companies have their name in the WHOIS data for their IP ranges it's a pretty easy way to identify them.

Comment: Lead Forensics are a little scary. I've seen what they can do.